# Bufferedoutputstream is much slower than the FTP

Tags: android, ftp

I sent file to the SD card of a server from the android application by using 2 methods:

1. by using FTP (Apache lib)
2. by using BufferedOutputStream to a specific socket

I found that the FTP method is about ten times faster than the BufferedOutputStream.

For example, to transfer a 3 Mbytes MP3 file takes 3 seconds for FTP while it takes 30 seconds for the method 2.

So, my question is:

1. why is it?
2. How to improve the BufferedOutputStream method? Can it be as fast as the FTP method?

I had tried to enlarge the buffer size by using `socket3.setReceiveBufferSize(32 * 1024);` However, I had no luck.